# When is DataView available?

Tags: extjs, combobox, initialization

I am trying to initialize an Ext JS ComboBox when the render event is fired.  However, it appears the DataView for the ComboBox is not available and an exception is thrown (this.view is undefined).

I can't use the "value" option when I configure a ComboBox as I don't have a value - rather I have a display value.

When can I set the value of a ComboBox?

Comment: Put the code here you are using. And, use the same field for displayField and valueField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried if `afterRender` event of [ExtJS Combobox](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.ComboBox?class=Ext.form.ComboBox) would work any better? Also, perhaps you could share your code - it would be a bit easier to understand the problem then. (Not sure why you need to reference the Dataview.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Yes, I tried the afterrender event - no luck.  I ended up finding a way to use the value parameter when I created the combobox.